# How to use crosstab function in DBIx::Class

Tags: sql, postgresql, catalyst, dbix-class

I am trying to use DBIx::Class in a Catalyst application to create a SQL statement that will produce results in a crosstab list. Here is an example of the SQL I am trying to produce.

```
select * from crosstab('
    select event_member_id, round, gross from results where event_id = 21 and round = 6 or round = 7 order by 1, 2')
    AS results(player integer, Saturday integer, Sunday integer)
;
```

I've attempted to create a custom method titled cross_tab that looks like this:

```
    sub cross_tab {
    my $self = shift;
    my $attributes = shift || {};

    $attributes->{'select'} = "* from crosstab('
        select event_member_id, round, gross from results where
        event_id = 21 and
        round = 6 or round = 7
        order by 1, 2')"
    ;`enter code here`

    $attributes->{'as'} = [
        'results(player integer, Saturday integer, Sunday integer)',
    ];

    return $self->search({}, $attributes);

}
```

This creates SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT me.* from crosstab('
    select event_member_id, round, gross from results where 
    event_id = 21 and 
    round = 6 or round = 7 
    order by 1, 2') 
FROM results me;
```

This is fairly close, but I don't want the "me" appended at the beginning nor do I want to add the addition FROM statement "FROM results me". I assume this is added by the search method.

Is there a better DBIx::Class method to use besides "search" or is there a way to tell DBIx::Class not to add the additional clause?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want the 'me' in there. DBIC adds that all the time, and it doesn't get in the way as it is filtered out when you process the data in the resultset.

The easiest way is to get what you want done is probably to create a [virtual view](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource/View.pod). You can then define the exact query in that view, and select directly on the resultsource as if it was any other table in your schema.

You can possibly also achieve a similar result with a subquery and some custom SQL through the backreferenced string syntax ( `\'sql literal'`), though all in all it would be harder.

Something like this should do:

```perl
package MyApp::Schema::Result::VirtualCrosstab;

use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;

__PACKAGE__->table_class('DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View');

__PACKAGE__->table('virtual_crosstab');
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->is_virtual(1);
__PACKAGE__->result_source_instance->view_definition(qq[
    select * from crosstab(
        select event_member_id, round, gross
        from results
        where event_id = 21 and round = 6 or round = 7 order by 1, 2
    )
    AS results(player integer, Saturday integer, Sunday integer)
;
]);
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  'player' => {
    data_type => 'integer',
    is_auto_increment => 1,
  },
  'saturday' => {
    data_type => 'integer',
  },
  'sunday' => {
    data_type => 'integer',
  },
);

1;
```

Comment: This answer works OK. The only issue I have now is trying to replace the where clause with dynamic values. Is it possible to add a placeholder?